# Programmatic aspect ratio constraints break when table view cells are dequeued

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am essentially trying to mimic the look and feel of Instagram's timeline view, which allows for photos of various aspect ratios to be displayed in a `UITableViewCell`, and to sit flush against the left and right margins of the view.

As of now, I have auto-layout constraints set for trailing and leading set to the superview, both set with a constant of 0, and bottom space and top space constraints set for the surrounding elements. As far as the image itself, I have it set to an aspect ratio constraint of 16:9, but ticked to "remove at build time", as images may sometimes have a different aspect ratio (16:12 is one).

Since I'll have access to the image's dimensional information in the downloaded JSON file before downloading the related images asynchronously, I want to set the height / width constraints of the image when the tableView is created with the JSON data. As of now, I'm creating the constraints in the UITableViewCell subclass within a function that is called from the UITableViewController's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Here is the code I'm using to create constraints:

```
    func configurePostTableViewCell(post: Post) {

        self.newsfeedPhotoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let photoHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(post.photoHeight)
        let photoWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(post.photoWidth)

        let aspectRatioConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.timelinePhotoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.timelinePhotoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: (photoHeight / photoWidth), constant: 0)
        aspectRatioConstraint.identifier = "$programmaticAspectRatio$"
        self.timelinePhotoImageView.addConstraint(aspectRatioConstraint)

    }
```

As I mentioned, the function itself is called within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and I've tried using the same code with `cell.` within the `tableViewController`, but the end result is the same:

When I build and run, the code at first seems to work perfectly, with both photos of different aspects being displayed correctly. The problem however, is when I scroll down 11 or so rows and (I'm assuming) the first few cells are dequeued for re-use. I set up a property observer in the cell to print to console when the cell is de-initialized, and the following error appeared at the same time the cells were dequeued:

```
2016-03-08 23:59:34.277 MyProject[12255:8479975] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c2c31820 '$timelinePhotoLeading$' H:|-(0)-[MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe8c2d13cb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c2d0b230 '$timelinePhotoTrailing$' H:[MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe8c2d13cb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c2d1b3d0 '$programmaticAspectRatio$' MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.height == 0.75*MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c0dae7f0 '$programmaticAspectRatio$' MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.height == 0.5625*MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c2d2e220 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe8c2d13cb0(375)]>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe8c2d1b3d0 '$programmaticAspectRatio$' MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.height == 0.75*MyProject.AsyncImageView:0x7fe8c2d16080.width>
```

When I scroll back up to the top, the 16:12 photo no longer sits flush with the left and right margins, and appears to be taking the constraint of the 16:9 photo (which is consistent from what I'm inferring from the error message). If I'm understanding the error correctly, it seems the cell is trying to apply both constraints (16:9 and 16:12) to the same cell, despite what is specified in the code... which is what's causing the conflict. The `tableViewController` subclass is holding an array of "post" objects, each of which has a height / width value saved for its associated image, but it doesn't seem that data is being used after the cell is dequeued.

So my question is what am I supposed to do, to prevent these constraints from being messed up after being dequeued? Furthermore, after the error message appears, none of the following 16:12 images are appearing correctly, and I get the same error message a few more times (additional JSON is downloaded every 8 posts or so... similar to Instagram or Facebook, etc).

[Here is a visual explanation of what's going wrong...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuLpb.jpg)

[The first two images in that gallery reflect the intended appearance, but this third image depicts the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm92E.jpg)

I've been struggling with this problem for at least a week now, and I'm not sure if there's something wrong in my strategy or if there is an additional function that I need to be calling when new cells are added and old ones are recycled. If anyone has any ideas or would like to see more of my code, I'd be very grateful for the assistance.

**EDIT:** Thanks to the help of the commenters below, I was able to fix my problem by removing the already existing aspect ratio constraint and then assigning the desired values from the UITableViewController to create a new one:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.row]

    let photoHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(post.photoHeight)
    let photoWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(post.photoWidth)
    cell.aspectRatio = photoHeight / photoWidth
    cell.configurePostTableViewCell(post)

    return cell

}
```

And in the UITableViewCell itself:

```
var aspectRatioLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var aspectRatio: CGFloat! {
    didSet {

        self.postPhotoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if self.aspectRatioLayoutConstraint != nil {

            self.postPhotoImageView.removeConstraint(self.aspectRatioLayoutConstraint)

        }

    self.aspectRatioLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.postPhotoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.postPhotoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: aspectRatio, constant: 0)
    self.postPhotoImageView.addConstraint(aspectRatioLayoutConstraint)
    self.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: Check your constraint in your storyboard, there might be duplicate. Or even constraint that cannot be there in the same time like you had `leading space` and `trailing space` but you still set its `width`

Comment: It seems you are not removing the __older__ aspect ratio constraint from a cell before you apply the new ratio when a cell is being reused. This can cause two aspect ratio constraints to be applied on same cell causing a conflict. Look closely you can see 2 constraint values in your error description. Make sure that you create an IBOutlet for this constraint and instead of applying a new constraint, just modify the existing one with new ratio.

Comment: As @Gandalf has mentioned what you need to do is just remove the older constraints before adding new one this will solve your problem and also you can identified that the problem by just try to scroll for more time like say 5 or 10 times and you will find that much of constraints added to your view

Comment: If I set the aspect ratio constraint as an IBOutlet as @Gandalf suggested, it seems the multiplier value cannot be set during `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as multiplier is a get-only value... so what I've done is to set up an `aspectRatio` variable in the UITableViewCell subclass, with a `didSet` observer which builds an aspectRatioLayoutConstraint with the values passed to it, and then adds the constraint to the UIimageView. I put a check at the beginning of the observer to check if there is already a constraint, and to remove it if so. I really appreciate the help from you both! So relieved!